# Graph Nx execution CPU and memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I have a Nx project with multiple packages in it. My goal is to produce graphs for the total CPU and memory used by all Nx tasks. As Nx starts separate processes for every package this seems non trivial.

The system on which I want to record is x86 Linux.

I looked at perf and top commands but I am not sure they can handle the subproceses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found this: https://nx.dev/recipes/other/performance-profiling

it produces JSON in a format for Chrome dev tools like so:

```
{
  "name": "library-name",
  "cat": "library-name",
  "ph": "X",
  "ts": 1000.1355486486,
  "dur": 2000.17981765465,
  "pid": 2684,
  "tid": 1,
  "args": {
    "target": {
      "project": "library-name",
      "target": "build"
    },
    "status": "local-cache"
  }
}
```

*numbers are not the real ones

If this is combined with a PID-based CPU and memory log for example from the top tool it is possible to create a CPU and memory profile per Nx job.

From there, the plotting is easy.